# gridlayout or table layout

Tags: android, tablelayout, grid-layout

I am trying to create a candy crush like game. Correct me if I'm wrong, but the way I see the basic logic of candy crush, several rows and columns were created and objects (e.g. candies) are placed on each box, forming a pattern will erase previous objects and will be replaced by a new one. My question is, shall I use a grid or table layout? Shall I create an array for objects (e.g. food, crackers) where it will be placed? are buttons in android shall be used to swap it with different objects?

Thanks for the help. Android newbie here. :)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely check out the official docs for your use-case. 
GridLayout:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html
TableLayout: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html

I'm not familiar with the candy crush game but from your description I would use a Table Layout as it looks like every item you'll have will stay in its' assigned cell. GridLayouts are very helpful if you have Views that extend past their cell boundaries. Just in case you should decide to use a GridLayout here's a wonderful article on them: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html

"Shall I create an array for objects (e.g. food, crackers) where it will be placed?" - That sounds like a fine thing to do to me!

"are buttons in android shall be used to swap it with different objects?" - Buttons are simply a type of View, replacing a Button with some other View inside a TableLayout should be pretty straight forward.

I know this was asked forever ago but maybe this could help someone? GL!